# Disabling MySQL remote access to root

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, root, whitelist

I have a *MySQL Installation* which has recently been compromised. Unfortunately this was due to another person leaving the '**root**' account remotely accessible. I am currently trying to create an *admin account* which is locked down to specific IP Addresses and revoke the remote access on root.

Problems:

- Custom admin account has specific IP Addresses set under "Host" but 
  currently is permitting connections from any IP Address.

  - Root user still allows remote logins despite Host being set to "127.0.0.1", "::1" and "localhost".

I have flushed the privileges after making the changes shown in the following screenshot, where I am at a loss. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: To have a `backups` user with access from everywhere (`%`) and almost all kind of privileges seems not better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run the following SQL script, to remove all access from remote hosts for the ‘root’ user

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');
```

After this perform `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: I should have mentioned I have already done that, although I just did so again with no luck. I ran both lines from PHPMyAdmin's SQL tab as well as directly in the MySQL CLI. After doing so, I am still able to login using root.

Comment: try to change authentication plugin to auth_socket

Answer (score 0):

Edit my.ini or my.cnf as follows:

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
skip-networking
```